# Distinguishing instances of a javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, local-storage

I am trying to create a wrapper for `localStorage.setItem()` so that I can listen for changes throughout my app.  Here is where I am right now, and it works as expected:

```
var _setItem = Storage.prototype.setItem;

Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key) {
    localStorage.______tmp = true;
    if( this.______tmp ) {
        delete this.______tmp;
        localStorageObservable.notifySubscribers(key);
    }
    _setItem.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

As you can probably guess, I would like to get rid of the whole _____tmp thing, but I need to know when setItem is being invoked on localStorage and not sessionStorage.  Is there a more elegant way to do what I need?   My initial attempt was to create an instance method by doing the following:

```
var _setItem = localStorage.setItem;
localStorage.setItem = function(key) { 
     _setItem.apply(this, arguments); 
}
```

But this causes a bug in Firefox where `typeof localStorage.setItem === "string"` ([I know, wierd right?](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/j80p7y8a/)).  I don't care about trying to solve that though as it feels better using the prototype anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `this` value directly:

```
var _setItem = Storage.prototype.setItem;

Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key) {
    if (this === localStorage) {
        localStorageObservable.notifySubscribers(key);
    }
    _setItem.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j80p7y8a/2/)

Comment: Wow, so crazy how the simple solution just blows right over sometimes.  Thanks.

Comment: Hah no problem, took me a little while to figure it out as well. `=]`